# Laravel session not updating through AJAX request

Tags: ajax, laravel, session, datatables, session-variables

Im trying to add filters to a jquery datatable by storing the filters in session, and refreshing the table everytime the user changes the filters. I already did this in another project implemented in Java, Servlets and JSP, but i'm struggling to reproduce it in Laravel, as the session doesn't update.

I have an AJAX request containing some data (the filters) which goes to a controller, which then updates the session. Below is the code on each of the steps:

AJAX:

```
    $.ajax({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        },
        url: '/ajax/collection/updateFilters',
        method: 'POST',
        data: {
            colorFilter: colorFilter,
            rarityFilter: rarityFilter,
            typeFilter: typeFilter
        },
        success: function(response) {
            console.log('Success');
            console.log(response);
        },
        error: function(response) {
            console.log('Error');
            console.log(response);
        }
    });

    // Update DataTable
    $('#collection-table').DataTable().draw();
```

> colorFilter, rarityFilter and typeFilter are all javascript objects

Controller:

```
public function updateFilters()
    {
        $color_filter = request('colorFilter');
        $rarity_filter = request('rarityFilter');
        $type_filter = request('typeFilter');

        session()->forget('collection');
        session([
            'collection' => [
                'mana' => $color_filter,
                'rarity' => $rarity_filter,
                'type' => $type_filter,
            ]
        ]);

    }
```

I can't figure out why the session is not updating. The funny thing is that if I `print_r(session()->all())` it prints out the updated session, but when it gets back from the controller, the session is not updated.

Do you guys have any idea why this is happening?

Additional info:

- Laravel session driver is set to file

UPDATE:

My DataTable initialization uses AJAX and is as follows:

```
function initTable() {

    $('#collection-table').DataTable({
        "pageLength": 25,
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": {
            "url": '/ajax/collection/getCollection',
            "type": 'POST',
            "data": {
                "_token": $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        },
        ... more options not relevant
    });

}
```

And my `getCollection` function inside the controller is as follows:

```
        if ( session()->get('collection.rarity.uncommon') == 'true' ) {
            $filtered = $filtered->merge($collection->where('rarity', 'uncommon'));
        }
```

Comment: How are you reading the "new" session information? I think you can't get the new session info from JS without refreshing the page. You should probably return a JSON object with the new data and read that instead. Leave the session approach just for the initial page load.

Comment: Laravel can't update the session without a page reload? This approach worked so well with java servlets

Comment: I'm not saying that you can't update the session with AJAX, what I'm saying is that *probably* you cant' read the *new session* from JavaScript. Could you post the code where you read the updated session? But, again, you could -in addition to update the session- return a JSON object with the new information and use that instead.

Comment: Yes, I can, i will copy and paste in the post. Returning a JSON would actually make it very difficult for me to update the table data the way I implemented.

Comment: Ok, now I understand what you are doing. In your first AJAX (the filters one), I think [draw()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/draw()) it is not the correct method to call. Try [ajax.reload()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.reload()). `$('#collection-table').DataTable().ajax.reload();`

Comment: I got very excited but it didn`t work. It seems that everytime i send a new AJAX request the session gets reset. I store the filters in the session, it gets updated, but then with the AJAX from datatable it gets reset.

Comment: Do a `dd(session()->get('collection'))` to see if it really isn't being updated. `rarity` has a javascript array as you said, don't know if you are accessing its values correctly. Change the PHP code AFTER the page load, so it only shows the `dd` when you change the filters.

Comment: I did something which i'm not proud of. I'm using mongodb, so i created a db collection to store what I wanted to store in the session, updated it and retrieved it from ajax.reload().

Answer (score 2):

I faced a similar problem. As you see the results via print_r(), they were written to the session file but for a while. I think some other requests are going and trigger `session()->save()`  function after your ajax request.

Something like this may happen

1. Your request runs - it opens the session file.
2. Another one (or few) is running immediately and triggers `session()->save()`
3. Request #1 saves its data in the session file.
4. `session()->save()` from request #2 finishes.  And overwrites savings from #3

The data from request #1 is lost.

Moreover request #2 may not work with session function in your code, but it triggers `session()->save()` under the hood.

I see two variants on how to handle this:

1. Make your request the last one in the request's set or give it some timeout. Not very useful.
2. Make session blocking https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/session#session-blocking so you will control concurrent requests.